# css selector for element that only has text as child

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want a CSS selector that will only give me the first 3 `<li>`s below that has no dom children. `:empty` doesn't work because it text are considered children.

```
 <ul>
  <li>I want this one</li>
  <li>I want this one</li>
  <li>I want this one</li>
  <li><a href="...">Not this one</a></li>
  <li><a href="...">Not this one</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that as a general rule, as you would need a parent selector, but...

...as you want to target text only, you can use the `:empty` selector in combination with an attribute and a pseudo element

```css
ul li:empty::after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  color: red;
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-text="I want this one"></li>
  <li data-text="I want this one"></li>
  <li data-text="I want this one"></li>
  <li><a href="...">Not this one</a></li>
  <li><a href="...">Not this one</a></li>
</ul>
```